# angularjs ngupload how to a show loader

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

http://ng-upload.eu01.aws.af.cm/

if you run the first example

you can see a simple loader

please wait ...

but I didn't find a way to integrate in the code example

```
<form ng-upload="bar" action="/upload?delay=yes">
                <p>
                    <label>Select a file to upload:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn upload-submit" value="Submit" />
                    <br />
                    <i>Button is <b>disabled</b> during upload, by default. (See Example 2 to change this).</i>
                </p>
            </form>
            <div class="alert alert-info">Server Response: {{uploadResponse}}</div>

var app = angular.module('ngUploadApp', ['ngUpload']);
        app.controller('Example1Ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.foo = "Hello World";
            $scope.bar = function (content) {
                console.log(content);
                $scope.uploadResponse = content;
            }
        });
```

in firebug I can see

Please wait...

ng-upl...s.af.cm (line 167)

"8d5deaa692b62b04771df8dc7357f797.jpg" uploaded to the server at Tue Jan 21 2014 20:45:32 GMT+0000 (UTC)

but I don't understand the logic behind it :(

may be the server get two response but it seems quite strange.

Can you help me, please ?

Comment: Here's a couple repos I manage: http://clouddueling.github.io/angular-common and https://github.com/clouddueling/angularjs-drag-drop-upload Might be able to help.

Comment: it seems good thanks I take it a look :)

Comment: and your profile + youtube channel is amazing :D thanks for sharing

Comment: Ty! ngUpload was a bit weird for me to get up and running smoothly and thus the two repos ;).